# How to stop RewriteRule overruling Redirect 301 in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, migration, http-status-code-301

I would like to make some massive redirects in .htaccess because of a migration. I'm using both RewriteRule and Redirect 301. But the RewriteRule keeps overwriting the Redirect 301 rules, despite of the order.

**For example:**

I would like to redirect /retraites-nl-cat-595.html to https://www.vihara.nl/meditatieretraites/
But all the other url's that contains 595 to https://www.vihara.nl/tag/vipassana/

**I have this in .htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.vihara.nl [R=301]
Redirect 301 /retraites-nl-cat-595.html https://www.vihara.nl/meditatieretraites/
RewriteRule ^(.*)595(.*)$ https://www.vihara.nl/tag/vipassana/ [L,R=301]
```

But this is not working because the RewriteRule is overruling the Redirect 301 rule. The same happens when I switch the order of the last 2 lines.

Is there a way to change this? So the Redirect 301 will be overruling the Rewrite rule, instead of the other way around?

Comment: RewriteRule and Redirect are handled by different modules, so I think it depends on their execution order, and the order of the directives in the .htaccess itself doesn’t change anything about that. You should probably use a RewriteCond before your RewriteRule that checks if the requested path is not the special one.

Comment: Or simply use a RewriteRule for that “special” redirect as well.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will try that and let you know.

Comment: I did not get it working unfortunately :(

Comment: I added that RewriteRule for that special redirect on top but it still did not overrule. After that I added a double one at the bottom of the .htaccess but that did not help either.

Comment: Edit your question with the updated version of what you tried. And make sure to test in a private tab, or clear your browser history, otherwise it is terribly easy to just get fooled by the cache when testing changes to the rewriting setup.